# Woocommerce and conditional statements to remove cart button for out of stock products

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm trying to write a conditional statement in my functions.php file to check if an item is in stock or not. Right now I am using the following code to replace the cart button on the product archive pages with a quantity label and input as well as the add to cart button (they are inline like in the single product page)

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');     //removes ajax Add To Cart button`
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30); //replaces singluar cart button with QTY input as well as cart button
```

Since I want those to disappear when the product is out of stock, I thought I could write something like this:

```
function backorder_msg() {
global $product;
if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart'); // remove that ajaxified Add To Cart button that automatically adds 1 item to the cart.
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30); // replace it with the Add To Cart Button, complete with QTY field.. the same one that is used on the Single Product page.
} else {

}
add_action('get_header', 'backorder_msg');
```

Now, this obviously doesn't work. One reason is because of the `get_header` hook I'm using; I'm not sure what to use there. I'm also not sure what to write within the else statement. If I delete those two actions then that area just reverts back to the default woocommerce cart button (which I'll want gone as well and replace with some text). Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Doesn't woocommerce already do that?

Comment: @pguardiario Any idea how?

Comment: I mean, WC should not show add to cart for out of stock items.

Comment: @pguardiairio Maybe it's messed up because of the custom actions. Regardless, still looking for a way to hide the 2nd action.

Comment: You might have an easier time hiding it with jquery.

Comment: Yes WooCommerce does this automatically. Look at the default `single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` template. There is `if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) :` right before showing the add to cart button. You shouldn't need any custom functions at all, but I would check your theme's template overrides.